# How to list microk8s' containers with microk8s.ctr

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, containerd

I created a microk8s cluster, pods could be listed by `get pod` command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-34:~$ microk8s.kubectl get pod --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system     coredns-f7867546d-mlsbm                      1/1     Running   1          98m
kube-system     hostpath-provisioner-65cfd8595b-l2hjz        1/1     Running   1          98m
kube-system     tiller-deploy-758bcdc94f-cwbjd               1/1     Running   0          93m
seldon-system   seldon-controller-manager-54955d8675-72qxn   1/1     Running   0          33m
```

However, I tried to list containers with ctr, nothing showing

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-34:~$ microk8s.ctr c ls
CONTAINER    IMAGE    RUNTIME
```

---

also try image list

```
$ microk8s.ctr image list
REF TYPE DIGEST SIZE PLATFORMS LABELS
```

nothing :P maybe I need to find which namespace it used ?

Comment: how about become root and then try

Comment: whats the `microk8s.ctr images list` output?

Comment: images list shows nothing (updated to my question)

Answer (score 6):

I found the correct namespace for `microk8s.ctr` from issue https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/756

it works after adding `-n k8s.io`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-34:~$ microk8s.ctr -n k8s.io c ls | head
CONTAINER                                                           IMAGE                                                                      RUNTIME
040bd2dcc65ecbd5cd6fc6621ed8059864d0b9f33ac1a5bac129ba3da9d45993    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
04b368611ede93ad9bcc90c1cca2e0285697a85e51afb7a8acd60e73ee27dc2a    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
050b0a44da4f89b34a4d415c0b584dc6c01fad3ba4ad5676e291113efe889099    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
0e807caf6967f11eff003fb4dd756b1c9665b3c72297903189b3478fe7b46bc1    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
144f38f7bd30bdff65a79fd627f52545612cc8669e5851ca4e6d80b99004b546    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
164bc117c9b128632be3466ce50408be5bf32e68bcc3fd6e062d7f1ec2ab89f6    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
16fae375f02bc617dd99f102f0230954ec71a4850c3428b86215b05977679a24    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                                                       io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
18389fce9a2c4bd4fab9a0e2d905592a9df8b73a7bdf1e42a314b7e7e557187e    docker.io/jupyterhub/configurable-http-proxy:4.1.0                         io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
1e56ccf5a49df5b3acda2ca0634bc8661da91476c0a611deeb96cd2190b66985    docker.io/metacontroller/jsonnetd:0.1                                      io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
```